# Python Tkinter: create a menu button on the right side

Tags: python, python-2.7, menu, tkinter

I am able to create a window with a menu and its sub-menus. However, I would like to create a single MenuButton on the right side. How do I do that?

```
 menubar = Menu(self.parent)
 self.parent.config(menu = menubar)
 self.fileMenu = Menu(menubar)
 self.fileMenu.add_command(label = "New")
 menubar.add_cascade(label = "File", menu = self.fileMenu)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do it. The menubar is a native widget that provides very little opportunity for customization.

Answer (score 1):

just give spaces in the first label until it gets the distance desire.

add_command(label=" 'replace this quotes with all empty spaces' options")